# Windows phone OS 7.0 vs OS 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, operating-system, push-notification, mpns

I am creating a new WP7 application on visual studio and the first thing it asks me to do is to target a WP OS version.

I have 2 options , 7.0 and 7.1  .

I am trying to make a simple app , implementing push notifications. I see on the tutorial from microsoft that is for OS 8.0 and 7.1 . What does that mean? That it wont run in OS 7.0 if i choose 7.1?

IF i develop it for 7.0 will it work at all and if yes will it run on 7.1 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

7.0 is the very first version of Windows Phone 7 with no updates.
7.1 is the internal version number for Windows Phone 7.5 (codename for this was Mango).

All new phones that run Windows Phone 7 are 7.5.  Most phones have an update available to update from 7.0 to 7.5.

Considering that there are very few pure 7.0 phones left, I would compile your app for 7.1 internal version, which is 7.5 external version.

Also, I am not sure even if the Windows Phone Store even accepts pure 7.0 apps anymore either.

Comment: Yes, You can no longer distribute apps to devices running 7.0 through the marketplace. If you use VS2012 and the latest SDK you cannot target even 7.0

Comment: Thank you too Matt for the very useful clarification.

Comment: to answer the other part of OS 8.0 and 7.1. You can not be bothered about 7.0. If you compile for 7.1 then it will work on 7.1 and in all likelihood for 8.0 (though the experience on 8.0 will not be good so I would recommended recompiling for 8.0). If you develop for 8.0, then you can't target 7.1